# Como ocultar la url en Laravel de forma dinamica

Tags: laravel, routes

Encontre esta solución utilizando `Encryption` para mostrar el parámetro de la url encriptado. Aplicando desde la vista, emplearía `encrypt` desde blade

```
<a href="{{route('aprobacion.edit',Crypt::encrypt($aproba->id))}}"
```

Y en el controlador poder `desencriptar` el valor.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

public function edit($id){

  $identificador =  Crypt::decrypt($id);
  
  $aprobacion = Aprobacion::find($identificador );

  return view('aprobacion.editar_aprobacion',compact('guest'));
}
```

Pero este metodo me obliga a ir por todas las rutas y funciones agregando `Crypt::encrypt` y `Crypt::decrypt` y quisiera encontrar la manera de configurar esto en un solo lugar y se aplique automaticamente en todas las funciones que pasan parametros por el `GET`

Comment: Si lo que querés es no mostrar el ID real del modelo, podes usar este paquete: https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId

Comment: Me gustaría hacerlo en un solo lugar y que sirva para todas las funciones sin tener que ir función por función configurando

Comment: A qué te referís con "función por función"? Lo que te pasé solo necesita que definas algo en cada modelo donde lo necesites, eso es todo. En los métodos de los controladores no tenés que hacer nada.